# Can not clone from gitlab using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

I have installed on DigitalOcean my GitLab (GitServer) and it is running Ok. I also have on DigitalOcean a LAMP stack (WebServer) and it is running Ok.

I successfully can clone into my computer any repo from my GitServer, I have added my ssh key to GitServer.

I also have added my WebServer's SSH key to my GitServer, but I can not clone from it.

This is what I get:

```
sudo git clone git@GitServer:group/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
git@GitServer: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Maybe Im missing something, I have followed tons of tutorials with no luck.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT - AFTER ALL FEEDBACK FOUND MY ANSWER**

Please take note that the command I used was:

```
sudo git clone git@GitServer:group/repo.git
```

The SSH key that I added to my server was my user's SSH key. After creating a new pair of keys for root user and adding it to my GitServer, no more *Permission denied (publickey)* issue.

This will be solved either adding your user to the www-data group and giving right permissions to the /var/www/ folder (and not cloning using sudo) or just use sudo and add the root's SSH key to the server, like I did at the end.

Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Does the WebServer's user have read access to the repository? This error is usually either mismatched keys or a user permission issue.

Comment: The only user in the WebServer is me, and I am the owner of the repo. Or maybe Im missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a permissions issue.

Your ssh key is not authorized - `Permission denied (publickey)`.

You need to create a public ssh key and to add the ssh public key again, delete older one.

Comment: Is it ok with HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, via https is ok, but I need it via SSH. I think Im missing something.

Comment: You create a ssh key and add same ssh key in your repo, isn't it?

Comment: I added the WebServer's SSH key to gitlab, not to the repo

Comment: without sudo:

    fatal: could not create work tree dir 'ltur': Permission denied

Comment: try these `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26022` and `https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/171`

Comment: may be you face something like this https://serverfault.com/a/932227/503355

Comment: Do I need to have a git user in my WebServer?

Comment: Not sure, but you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, please review my edits to the question and you will see the answer there. Your feedback was important to get to the key solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to have a git user in my WebServer?

That is what `git@GitServer` means: "connect to `GitServer` as user `git`".
Your GitLab server should be running as user `git`.

That also means your public key must be added to `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` for any SSH-related operation to have a chance to work.
That should be done automatically by GitLab on your remote server when you add your key to your profile.

Check the output of `ssh -Tv git@GitServer`; you [should see a Welcome message](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly).

Using `sudo` means your public/private keys must be in `/root/.ssh`, for a `sudo git clone git@...` command to complete an ssh session successfully.

Comment: After your answer and some more debugging, I found out that I was trying to clone from my user but connected as root. This was the reason why the SSH key was not working.

Will continue to test and let you all know. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, please review my edits to the question and you will see the answer there. Your feedback was important to get to the key solution.

Comment: @EduardoSánchez That seems coherent: using sudo means root has the keys. I have edited my answer accordingly.